# Error al grabar DataFrame Python a tabla Mysql

Tags: mysql, python, pandas

Tengo un dataframe con la siguiente estructura y datos, 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y deseo grabarlo en una base de datos MySql, con el siguiente código:

```
import mysql_conn as my
import pandas as pd 

conn = my.connect()
ventanas.to_sql("seasonalwindows",conn,if_exists="replace")
```

Y me está dando este error que no consigo saber porqué es:

> OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown column 'infe0' in 'field list'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO seasonalwindows (`index`, `Ticker`, `CodWindow`, `RtdadMedia`, `RtdadTotal`, `Sharpe`, `Rating`, `Porcalza`, `DiaIni`, `MesIni`, `DiaFin`, `MesFin`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'] [parameters: ((0, '2HR_FSE', 1010125, -1.2653653846153834, -15.132999999999994, -1.04, -59.0, 0.5555555555555556, 1.0, 1.0, 26.0, 1.0), (1, '2HR_FSE', 1260211, 3.5284487179487183, 46.716, 4.69, 64.0, 0.5555555555555556, 26.0, 1.0, 12.0, 2.0), (2, '2HR_FSE', 2120214, -0.5213589743589742, -5.716999999999999, -3.59, -59.0, 0.5370370370370371, 12.0, 2.0, 15.0, 2.0), (3, '2HR_FSE', 2150223, 1.5053653846153843, 19.799999999999997, 6.11, 62.0, 0.5277777777777778, 15.0, 2.0, 24.0, 2.0), (4, '2HR_FSE', 2240323, -5.1995495337995346, -63.65100000000002, -3.39, -55.0, 0.4777777777777778, 24.0, 2.0, 24.0, 3.0), (5, '2HR_FSE', 3240514, 9.962610606060606, 110.908, 4.57, 70.0, 0.48148148148148145, 24.0, 3.0, 15.0, 5.0), (6, '2HR_FSE', 5150606, -2.93565675990676, -35.575, -3.71, -57.0, 0.4523809523809524, 15.0, 5.0, 7.0, 6.0), (7, '2HR_FSE', 6070624, 2.418203962703963, 27.777000000000008, 4.24, 62.0, 0.4583333333333333, 7.0, 6.0, 25.0, 6.0)  ... displaying 10 of 58884 total bound parameter sets ...  (58882, 'Z_NASDAQ', 12171224, -1.6553619047619046, -8.018999999999998, -3.44, -58.0, 0.4367816091954023, 17.0, 12.0, 26.0, 12.0), (58883, 'Z_NASDAQ', 12261227, 1.9307, 9.854, 14.17, 62.0, 0.43333333333333335, 26.0, 12.0, 28.0, 12.0))] (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

Muchas gracias y un saludo

Comment: Hola evalde, yo al menos no puedo reproducirlo con la información que proporcionas. ¿Si envías solo una fila a la BD te ocurre también? De no ser así intenta aislar la fila o filas causantes con el fin de poder reproducirlo. Las versiones de SQLAlchemy, pandas y MySql podrían ser también de ayuda. Yo me encontré hace un tiempo con un problema similar debido a valores `NaN` y hay por ahí documentados otros debidos a `np.inf`, pero no se me ocurre ahora mismo de dónde puede salir lo de "infe0"...

Answer (score 0):

No sé muy bien porqué ocurre el error que comentaba

> OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (1054, "Unknown
>   column 'infe0' in 'field list'")

Intenté localizar el error. El dataframe tenía 58883 registros y al tratar de guardarlos en la BBDD me salía el error. Traté de identificar el error reduciendo el número de registros, pero dependiendo del tamaño que dejara me salí el error o no.
No tenía, en ningún sitio, el campo o columna llamada "infe0".

Y finalmente solucioné el problema (aunque no de manera muy profesional ni muy convencido) añadiendo una columna nueva llamada "infe0" al dataframe.

Haciendo eso me dejó de salir el problema y se ma guardaba la tabla sin problema en la BBDD, pero con un campo añadido llamado "infe0" que no me sirve para nada y que ocupa espacio.

Si alguien sabe solucionar de una manera eficiente el problema, agradecería que me lo comentara. Un saludo y gracias